# The method getApplication() is undefined for the type error

Tags: android, instance

I have a class which extends activity and I call another class which extends view. Below you can see how I call:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GifView gifView = (GifView)findViewById(R.id.gifview);
}
```

In GifView Class, which extends View, I am trying to reach an instance of global class but I am having `The method getApplication() is undefined for the type GifView` error. Here you can see how I call it.

```
AppDelegate appDelegate = ((AppDelegate)getApplication());
```

I am wondering how can I reach `AppDelegate` class without getApplication error.

And here how I declared AppDelegate class:

```
public class AppDelegate extends Application {

    public AppDelegate() {
        instance = this;
    }
..
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getApplication%28%29.  `GifView` does not have a method by name `getApplication()` Activtiy does

Comment: GifView class extends View not Activity. So how can I reach from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it says that

```
The method getApplication() is undefined for the type GifView
```

that's because it's true.

Correct it to

```
AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate) gifView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

- [`View.getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext())
- [`Context.getApplicationContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext())

Or just use any other Context:

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    public void someMethod(SomeType someArgument) {
        AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate) getApplication();
        // have fun!
    }

}
```

Comment: I got error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getContext() from the type View.."

Comment: @gbesler: That's because you are calling `View.getContext()` instead of `gifView.getContext()`. You can also just call use any other Context, like `this` in Activities.

Comment: solved with "AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate) GifView.this.getContext().getApplicationContext();"

Comment: @gbesler: In that case, `AppDelegate appDelegate = (AppDelegate) getContext().getApplicationContext();` should work too.